# Сравнение результатов двух функций перебором

Tags: c++, математика

Я хотел написать программу, которая подставляет значения `x` и `y` под уравнение:

> 5 / (x + y) = 2 / (x -y)

Вот что получилось:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  int x,y;
  int firstResult  = 5 / (x + y);
  int secondResult = 2 / (x - y);
  for(x = 0; x < 200; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < 200; y++){
        if(firstResult == secondResult){
            cout << "x= " << x << " y= " << y << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "fail" << endl;
        }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Что здесь не так?

Comment: логическая ошибка. на 0 делить нельзя. цикл надо начинать с 1

Comment: y=3x/7:  x=3 -> y=9/7

Comment: формула вне цикла, зачем????

Comment: если "известно что x = 3", зачем `for(x = 0; x < 200; x++){`?

Comment: просто учусь решать задачи методом полного перебора

Comment: @SeniorAutomator - x = 1, y = 1 -> 2 / (x - y) ?

Comment: 5 / (x + y) = 2 (x - y)

Comment: @Igor потом уже обратил на это внимание

Answer (score 3):

Хотя бы так...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int x,y;
  for(x = 0; x < 200; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < 200; y++){
        if (x == y) continue;
        double firstResult  = 5.0 / (x + y);
        double secondResult = 2.0 / (x - y);
        if (abs(firstResult - secondResult) < 1e-10) {
            cout << "x= " << x << " y= " << y << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
  }
  cout << "fail" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Хотя - понятно, что при положительных `x` и `y` не имеет смысла проверять `x`, меньшие `y`.

P.S. Надеюсь, это вы не решали уравнение, а тренировались в программировании? :)

Comment: я просто щас в шкалке учусь я составил мат. модель реальной ситуации по задаче и решил проверить решение на компьютере

Comment: как раз хотел написать про double

Comment: и еще у тебя более точный результат!

Comment: Тогда `5(x-y) = 2(x+y)`, или `3x = 7y`, или, если `x==3`, то `y = 9/7`, т.е. никак не целое число...

Comment: как написать программу для решения системы уравнений для более точного результата?

Comment: Вещественное деление на 0 вполне себе валидно. Проверять знаменатель на 0 особого смысла нет.

Comment: @alexolut Ну... в принципе да...

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем коде имеется несколько проблем:

1. Использование не инициализированных переменных;
2. Целочисленное деление (+деление на 0);
3. Вычисление значений вне тела цикла;
4. Сравнение результатов вычисления;
5. Вывод сообщения о неудаче на каждой итерации.

Все эти проблемы могут быть [решены](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9jIVCERZwFPr5Mj0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    const double eps = 0.00001;
    bool found = false;
    for(int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 200; y++) {
            double firstResult  = 5. / (x + y);
            double secondResult = 2. / (x - y);
            if(std::abs(firstResult - secondResult) < eps) {
                cout << "x= " << x << " y= " << y << endl;
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Данное уравнение не имеет достаточно точного решения. И программа ниже это демонстрирует. То есть все результаты вычисления уравнения имеют большие погрешности.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>


int main() 
{
    const int N = 200;

    auto first_exp  = []( int x, int y ) { return 5.0 / ( x + y ); };
    auto second_exp = []( int x, int y ) { return 2.0 / ( x - y ); };

    bool found = false;

    int x = 0, y = 0;

    for ( ; !found && x < N; x++ )
    {
        for ( ; !found && y < N; y++ )
        {
            if ( x != y )
            {
                found = std::abs( first_exp( x, y ) - 
                                  second_exp( x, y ) ) < 
                        std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(); 
            }                               
        }
    }

    if ( found )
    {
        std::cout << "x = " << x << ", y = " << y << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "There is no solution in the range 0 - " << N << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


There is no solution in the range 0 - 200
```

Поэтому лучше написать программу так, чтобы она находила не точное решение, а лучшее из всех значений `x` и `y` на отрезке `[0, 200]` . В этом случае программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() 
{
    const int N = 200;

    auto first_exp  = []( int x, int y ) 
    { 
        return 5.0 / ( x + y ); 
    };
    auto second_exp = []( int x, int y ) 
    { 
        return 2.0 / ( x - y ); 
    };
    auto value      = [&]( int x, int y ) 
    { 
        return std::abs( first_exp( x, y ) - second_exp( x, y ) );
    };


    bool first = true;
    int best_x = 0, best_y = 0;

    for ( int x = 0; x < N; x++ )
    {
        for ( int y = 0; y < N; y++ )
        {
            if ( x != y )
            {
                if ( first || value( x, y ) < value( best_x, best_y ) )
                {
                    best_x = x; best_y = y;
                    first = false;
                }
            }                               
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The best values are x = " << best_x 
              << ", y = " << best_y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
The best values are x = 7, y = 3
```